# public key RSA encryption in react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, public-key-encryption

I've implemented the following encryption function in `node.js` which is working fine:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

/** USE AS: 
 * const encryptedKey = encryptWithPublicKey('testing encryption for today with a key').toString('base64')
 */
exports.encryptWithPublicKey=(key)=>{
    return crypto.publicEncrypt(
        {
            key: process.env.CRYPT_PUBLIC_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
            padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
            oaepHash: 'sha256',
        },
        Buffer.from(key)
    )
}
```

Is there any way to duplicate this functionality with the same padding and oaepHash in `react.js` (i.e. `encryptWithPublicKey` method only? - Because I want the client to encrypt with public key and node to decrypt with private key).

My node code (which is working) to decrypt with private key is:

```
/** USE AS: 
 * const decryptedkey=decryptWithPrivateKey(tempkey).toString('utf-8')
 */
exports.decryptWithPrivateKey=(encryptedKey)=>{
    return crypto.privateDecrypt(
        {
            key:process.env.CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
            padding:crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
            oaepHash:'sha256',
            passphrase:process.env.CRYPT_KEY_PAIR_PASSPHASE
        },
        Buffer.from(encryptedKey,'base64')
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');

const encryptWithPublicKey = (key) => {
  const publicKey = new NodeRSA(process.env.CRYPT_PUBLIC_KEY, 'pkcs8-public', {
  encryptionScheme: {
  scheme: 'oaep',
  hash: 'sha256',
  },
});

const encryptedData = publicKey.encrypt(key, 'base64');
return encryptedData;
};

// Usage example
const encryptedKey = encryptWithPublicKey('testing encryption for today with a key');
console.log(encryptedKey);
```

Comment: I'm getting: `errors.js:7 Uncaught InvalidAsn1Error: encoding too long at newInvalidAsn1Error (errors.js:7:1)`

Comment: Can you check the encoding of the key and the format.?

Comment: my key is of type RSA with bit length of 4096 with the output format of PEM. I've made a codesandbox on this: https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-glitter-3xjyrf?file=/src/App.js:1017-1124